# Radial Sobolev embedding

Tags: sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, integral-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, interpolation-theory

I'm trying to prove the following inequality $$\left\||x|f\right\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)}\lesssim \left\|f\right\|_{H^1(\mathbb{R}^3)},$$
for every radial function $f\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$, where $\left\|f\right\|_{H^1(\mathbb{R}^3)}:=\left\|f\right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}+\left\|\nabla f\right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}$. There's a hint that tells one should use the fundamental theorem of calculus and the cauchy-schwarz inequality.

**My attempt:**
Since i wasn't seeing any useful way to apply cauchy-schwarz i squared the l-h-s and used the FTC using that $f$ is radial, like this:
$$ ||x|f(x)|^2=\int_0^{|x|}\partial_r(r^2f(r)\overline{f(r)})dr=\int_0^{|x|}2r|f(r)|^2+2\Re \left(r^2\overline{f(r)}\partial_rf(r)\right)dr,$$
and now i could try to apply cauchy schwarz, but i think this isn't going anywhere because there are too many terms i don't want and don't know how to get rid of them. Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Are there any conditions on $n$?

Comment: I think your argument can (easily) show that $|x|^{(n-1)/2}f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, but this only agrees with your statement for $n=3$.

Comment: Actually yes, in the context i'm studying we have $n=3$, but this is a result from the preliminary section of the paper and i misread the statement and thought of it as a general result. I've edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: OK, then the idea is to use the FTC only on $|f|^2$, writing an integral $-\int_{|x|} ^\infty$ and then using Cauchy-Schwarz, keeping in mind polar coordinates in three dimensions.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Now i'm trying to estimate the integral in the real line with a integral outside the ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ using polar coordinates and the fact that f is radial. i'm also trying to use the identity $\partial_rf=\nabla f\cdot x/|x|$ to force the absolute value of $x$ to appear. but i still cannot see how i would take advantage of the fact that $n=3$ and use cauchy-schwarz.

Comment: There's a $|x|^2$ floating around, outside the integral, since you're estimating $|x|^2|f|^2$. Trade this inside the integral for an $r^2$ and put one of them on $f$ and the other on $f'$. Now use Cauchy-Schwarz.